# How to enable SettingDrawer in ant-design-pro v5

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

With `Ant Design Pro` v4, when init project, [by choosing the option `complete` scaffolding](https://beta-pro.ant.design/docs/getting-started#init), you'll get the [Setting Drawer](https://pro.ant.design/docs/layout#settingdrawer) out of the box.
[image]
But in v5, you won't be able to select the `complete` option (you can refer to this [demo video](https://beta-pro.ant.design/docs/getting-started#init), no *Do you need all the blocks or a simple scaffold* there), and **the default scaffold of v5 has no `SettingDrawer`**.

How to enable it in Ant Design Pro v5? I've read [this](https://pro.ant.design/blog/new-pro-use#settingdrawer) but not helpful because in v5 the Layout configuration code is quite different from v4. You may init the project in [v5 here](https://beta-pro.ant.design/docs/getting-started) and [v4 here](https://v4-pro.ant.design/docs/getting-started) to see what I mean by "quite different".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In And Design Pro v5, use various features by umi plugins. As for this feature, `/src/app.tsx` should like below:

```
// /src/app.tsx
import type { RunTimeLayoutConfig } from 'umi';
import { SettingDrawer } from '@ant-design/pro-layout';

import defaultSettings from '../config/defaultSettings';

// https://umijs.org/zh-CN/plugins/plugin-initial-state
export async function getInitialState() {
  // ...
  return {
    // others state
    settings: defaultSettings,
  }
}

// https://umijs.org/zh-CN/plugins/plugin-layout
export const layout: RunTimeLayoutConfig = ({ initialState, setInitialState }) => {
  return {
    // others props
    childrenRender: (dom) => {
      return (
        <>
          {dom}
          <SettingDrawer
            settings={initialState?.settings}
            disableUrlParams
            onSettingChange={(nextSettings) =>
              setInitialState({
                ...initialState,
                settings: nextSettings,
              })
            }
          />
        </>
      );
    },
  }
}
```